# NextJs SSR not recognizing CSS Media queries for mobile

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js

I just integrated Nextjs SSR into my React project. Before this, my css media queries for mobile-responsiveness were working perfectly. Now, when I use Chrome's tools to view my app on a mobile screen size or even on my own device, I get the view as if it's on desktop.

It seems like the server is rendering the entire page and assuming desktop size and not re-rendering when it hits the client. If that's the case, how do I tell it the user is mobile and to use those CSS queries?

Here are my media queries that don't seem to be working. I'm not using CSS in JS, maybe I should be? I'm using regular css files for each component.

```
.Footer {
    width: var(--webMaxContentWidth);
    height: 200px;
    background: #368efb;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .Footer {
        width: 100%;
        height: 400px;
        margin: 0 20px;
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Do you have a link to the project? I'd like to see this with dev tools opened.

Comment: @AndyHoffman Hey! thanks for the reply. I do not have a link to it at the moment.

Comment: When you view `.Footer` in the correct screen width for the media query to work, does it show up in the dev tools inspector? Are the styles being overridden somehow?

Comment: @AndyHoffman The .Footer does show in the dev tools inspector, but it shows with the wrong styles (not the media query styles). I'll add the default styles in my post.

Comment: Sorry if this is an obvious question, but do you have `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` in your `<head></head>`?

Comment: @AndyHoffman This is new stuff to me so no worries. Where would that be since NextJs is handling that? In my component in /pages for this component?

Comment: @AndyHoffman Wow. I just added that in my  component in my /pages directory and it solved the problem! I can't believe it. Why doesn't Nextjs do that automatically when they render the component in html? I wonder if I can add it once somewhere in Nextjs config so that I don't have to do that in every component.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Before, React was automatically inserting the following in the `<head>` of your SPA:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Once you moved to `SSR`, the responsibility moved to the developer to add this bit themselves. Without it, you'd have some very unexpected behavior when it came to `@media` query breakpoints. As you discovered after resolving your issue, this has been solved [already](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/5122).

Comment: This was causing problems for me for a while, tried some other search terms and could not find a helpful answer. Glad I finally found this.